# What is the use of the np.ndarray() function and how is it used?

Tags: numpy

I just started Data Science and I want to know what the `np.ndarray()` function's use is, and in which scenario(s) it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.ndarray` is not a function but a class, as you can see in [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

An `ndarray` is meant to store data, it is just a multidimensional matrix. You store your matrix data in an `ndarray` and then you operate on it, adding to other `ndarray`s, or any other matrix operation you want to compute. From the [documentation of `ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html):

> An ndarray is a (usually fixed-size) multidimensional container of items of the same type and size. The number of dimensions and items in an array is defined by its shape, which is a tuple of N non-negative integers that specify the sizes of each dimension. The type of items in the array is specified by a separate data-type object (dtype), one of which is associated with each ndarray.

While you can create yourself instances of `numpy.ndarray` by invoking its constructor, most of the times, arrays are created with the convenience function [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), which ends up creating and returning an instance of `numpy.ndarray`. For instance, let's create a 3x3 identity matrix manually:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
```

And now we can compute operations on it, e.g.:

```
b = a + a
print(b)
```

The result is:

```
[[2 0 0]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 0 2]]
```